# TextFormField enters value backwards [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, textfield, direction

As displayed in the GIF below, the `TextFormField` i am using is entering the values backwards. I have set the `TextDirection` property to `ltr` as well but it did not change anything. Other `TextFormFields` dont seem to be having this issue. The entered text is being sent back to another screen using `Navigator.pop` and it is sent in the same backwards manned.

[Weird TextFormField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RSqw.gif)

Code for the textFormField causing the issue:

```
TextFormField(
// validator: (String value) {
// return value.isEmpty ? "task must have a name" : null;
// },
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    maxLength: 100,
    controller: newcontroller, // Just an ordinary TextController
    onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
            newcontroller.text = value;
        });
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        errorText: _validate  // Just a boolean value set to false by default
                   ? 'Value Can\'t Be Empty' : null,
        labelText: "name of task"
    ),
    style: TextStyle(height: 1.2, fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black87)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can send whatever you want in **Navigator.pop(context,whtever you want to pass)**

```
  TextFormField(
//                        validator: (String value) {
//                          return value.isEmpty ? "task must have a name" : null;
//                        },
                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                maxLength: 100,
                controller: newcontroller, // Just an ordinary TextController
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print(value);
                },

                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    errorText:
                        _validate // Just a boolean value set to false by default
                            ? 'Value Can\'t Be Empty'
                            : null,
                    labelText: "name of task"),
                style:
                    TextStyle(height: 1.2, fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black87),
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, newcontroller.text);
                },
                child: Text("GO BACK!"),
              ),
```

Answer (score 11):

> You don't have to set text in  `newcontroller.text` when `onChanged` is called.
>   text  enter in your `TextFormField` is assigned by default to `newcontroller`.

You are getting this error because for this piece of code,

**So, try to remove below code**

```
 setState(() {
            newcontroller.text = value;
        });
```

Comment: Where is it mentioned in the Flutter doc ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html

Answer (score 3):

replace **onChanged** with **onEditingComplete**.

```
onEditingComplete: (value) {
            newController.text = value;
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); //use this to dismiss the screen keyboard
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the onChanged function. There is no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    onChanged: (val) {
              if (val.isNotEmpty) {
                setState(() {
        // remember to not add your controller value in onchanged 
                  _messageController.text = val;
                  isShowSendButton = true;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
        // remember to not add your controller value in onchanged 
                  _messageController.text = val;
                  isShowSendButton = false;
                });
              }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, onEditingComplete doesn't always fire (i.e. on a focus change), so if you are editing a text variable you can still use onChanged as the most reliable way to update changes, but you should not use the onChanged value parameter, nor should you use setState (which results in the reversed text).

```
        TextEditingController tec = TextEditingController(text: myText);
        return TextField(
          controller: tec,
          onChanged: (value) {
            myText = tec.text;
          },
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the TextField update both through a controller (maybe via a dropdown menu) and direct input, you can adjust the controller and the onChanged callback accordingly. Here's an example implementation:

```
    TextEditingController hometeamController = TextEditingController();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // Initialize the controller with the current value
  hometeamController.text = hometeam;
}

// ...

TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    hintText: '${(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.hometeam)}',
    labelText: '${(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.hometeam)}',
  ),
  controller: hometeamController,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      // Update the hometeam variable on every change
      hometeam = value;
    });
  },
),
DropdownButton<Welcome>(
  value: _selectedWelcome,
  onChanged: (Welcome? selectedWelcome) {
    // Handle the selected team
    setState(() {
      _selectedWelcome = selectedWelcome;
      // Update the controller with the selected team name
      hometeamController.text = selectedWelcome?.teamName ?? '';
    });
  },
  items: _welcomeList
    .map<DropdownMenuItem<Welcome>>(
      (Welcome welcome) => DropdownMenuItem<Welcome>(
        value: welcome,
        child: Text("${welcome.teamName} - Goals: ${welcome.goals}"),
      ),
    )
    .toList(),
),
```

In this example, the TextEditingController hometeamController is created and initialized with the current value of hometeam. The onChanged callback of the TextFormField then updates both the variable hometeam and the hometeamController.text.

When changing the selected team in the dropdown menu, not only is the variable _selectedWelcome updated, but also the hometeamController.text with the selected team name.

This way, the TextField will be updated through both direct input and the dropdown menu selection. And the input will have the right direction from left to right.

Principially you have to change four things:

1. after class _YourPageState extends State {...
   insert

   TextEditingController yourvariableController = TextEditingController();
2. after

   @override
   void initState() { ...
   //insert
   yourvariableController.text = yourvariable;
3. In the dropDownMenu or an other Function etc. insert in the onChanged (value) (or onSelected) setState(()....

   yourvariableController.text = selectedWelcome?.yourvariable ?? '';
4. finally in the TextFormField:

   controller: hometeamController,

before onChanged: (value) {...