# when i typing in flutter textfield it type in backward direction how to solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, textfield, flutter-textinputfield

I have one page of technical skill and I want to add new textfield on onatap and get the value of it and remove that skill on ontap of delete button and this is working now but only problem was that the when i am typing in textfield its typing in backward direction(right to left i want to type left to right.)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Technical extends StatefulWidget {
  const Technical({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Technical> createState() => _TechnicalState();
}

class _TechnicalState extends State<Technical> {
  List<String> skill = <String>[];
  List<TextEditingController> mycontroller = <TextEditingController>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: const Text(
          'Technical Skills',
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Enter Your Skills',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ...skill
              .map(
                (e) => Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: TextField(
                        enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                        controller: TextEditingController(text: e),
                        onChanged: (String value) {
                          setState(() {
                            skill[skill.indexOf(e)] = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            skill.remove(e);
                            mycontroller.clear();
                            print(e);
                          });
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete))
                  ],
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              '$skill',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                skill.add("");
              });
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the “backward direction” left to right or right to left?

Comment: right to left i want to type left to right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are creating new controller on every state change, the cursor position is not handling in this.

So the solution will we

```dart
controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
  TextEditingValue(
      text: e,
      selection: TextSelection(
        baseOffset: e.length,
        extentOffset: e.length,
      )),
),
```

With controller

```dart
class _TechnicalState extends State<Technical> {
  List<String> skill = <String>[];
  List<TextEditingController> mycontroller = <TextEditingController>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: const Text(
          'Technical Skills',
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Enter Your Skills',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          for (int i = 0; i < mycontroller.length; i++) row_build(i),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              '$skill',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              mycontroller.add(TextEditingController());
              setState(() {
                skill.add("");
              });
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Row row_build(int i) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          child: TextField(
            enableInteractiveSelection: true,
            controller: mycontroller[i],
            onChanged: (String value) {
              setState(() {
                skill[i] = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                skill.remove(skill[i]);
                mycontroller.removeAt(i);
              });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working but when i trying to type its laggy and when im trying to remove text its only remove one alphabet can you check???

Comment: It would be better if you use `mycontroller`, and laggy because on creating multiple controller and device performance

Comment: it's not working for me but thank you for your time.....

Comment: try to test on different device

Comment: your updated code with mycontroller is working but when i trying to remove its remove all textfield i wnatto remove only selected one....

Comment: do you mean deleting single item from list?

Comment: use ` mycontroller.removeAt(i);`

Comment: yes on ontap of delete icon..

Comment: try update one `mycontroller.removeAt(i);`

Comment: ook now it's working fine T#@nx @Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: For others, it maybe better to remove `onChange` since the controller already handles the change: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59091532/11777075

Answer (score 1):

The textfield works fine for me (left to right)

Check your code if the `textDirection` property is set correctly to `TextDirection.ltr` instead of `TextDirection.rtl`

```
child: TextField(
   textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
```

[image]

Comment: where you check android ios or web???????

Comment: in my web or android phone its backward..

Comment: wait i post wrong code now updated check it..